# Where should mental health questions go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am aware of a number of different sites which allow questions surrounding the issues of mental health to be asked. I was wondering which site would be best for the following question:

**Are anxiety and depression linked, and what are the reasons behind them commonly being treated together?**

A [quick search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=mental+health) means that there are a number of acceptable sites, which would be best in the context of this question?

Comment: Every site has their own meta support community where they develop what is on and off topic for their sites. You should be asking the folks who actual use those sites if your subject is a good fit there.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I currently do not have the rep to access meta on those sites which is why I am asking the question here.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I also hasent to add that this follows the exact guidelines of the site recomentationd tag as I am asking what site a question on mental health would go on. If this was not okay then there would not be a tag for it.

Comment: @RobertCartaino it does not pertain to a specific site because I am asking across all the sites on the Stack Exchange network, naming two as examples for my post, which would be the best place to awnser the question above. This fits the guidelines completely.

Comment: I would start with their 'Help' Centers beginning with the article "What topics can I ask about here?"  If you can narrow down the subject you'd like to ask, you will likely find a meta post covering the situation. Pick the site that best fits your question and let them take it from there. You are not expected to know all the nuances of every community, so that's why every community is entrusted with a good dose of community *self-* moderation to help you out once you post a question.

Comment: @RobertCartaino we have a tag for site recommendation. The description quotes "
After looking through the site list, https://stackexchange.com/sites, you don't know where to ask your question on the Stack Exchange Network? Give as much detail as possible about the question you'd like to ask, and the community will help you find the appropriate site." That is my current situation which is why this question is perfectly acceptable on this site

Comment: @JakeSymons But that's not what your question is asking.  It's asking what the scope is of several sites (and asking what the scope is of a given site is something you should be asking about on that site's meta, not here); you aren't asking which site you should ask your one question on.

Comment: @Servy after reading your comment I have taken time to reword the question, please inform me if you believe that it still needs work to be considered acceptbale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *could* be on topic on [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/), *but [with great care:](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*

- requests for a personal diagnosis (do I / my father / this person who totally isn't me have X?) or personal treatment recommendations (what should I do about my X?) *are totally off topic*
- questions are supposed to include some sort of information about what you already know, that is: your prior research on the topic, not just "tell me about X" and should ideally be quite crisp so that you can clearly say "yes, this is the correct answer to that."

Your possible question includes an assertion that two things are often treated together. So it should include some links to show what leads you to that conclusion, as well as other information you've gathered while looking into this. A crisper question than "are they linked" would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 2):

These type of questions should land  **[here at the Medical Sciences](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/113814/medical-sciences)** section; currently housed on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) where suggestions are launched for new sister-sites that address these new kind of topics.

Comment: Re Update: [Related MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383862/how-do-i-see-when-an-se-site-was-closed)