# How do I see when an SE site was closed?

Tags: support, area-51, closed-sites

It was announced today that the [Windows Phone SE site had been closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383855/the-windows-phone-se-site-has-been-archived#383855). The [Area 51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) lists that the site was closed after 3857 days, but is there a way to see what date an SE site was closed?

[image: Area 51 page for Windows Phone]

Comment: It is mentioned at right side https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJMhE.png

Comment: @JitendraSingh it's just a very rough estimation, it's not the ordinary timestamp with exact date as tooltip. For example, [this one](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating) says "It was closed 8 years ago", but it's impossible to know exact date from this. So it's nice to have for the first few days after closure, then it becomes rather useless if you're after the actual date.